# "Warning" about editing a read-only file although I have permission

Tags: linux

I am using VSCode to remotely connect to a file server via SSH. I have another person who uses it as well and they are logging in under their own account, which is a part of a group that has access to an entire directory structure.

Every once in a blue moon, the permissions get screwed and revert back to `root:root` (ownership) and I have to change it back to `root:groupname` so that the other person can have access. However, even when I do this, sometimes the other person isn't able to make changes using VS Code. If I `su` to that user, I am able to save changes.

One thing that I have noticed is that if I run `vim <filename>` and try to edit it as that user, it'll say, `"-- INSERT -- W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file"`. However, the minute I try to save the file, it actually saves.

It's almost like the permissions are lagging or something and hasn't been updated.

Any idea how I can go about fixing this?

Comment: It may be that one editor allows forcing the write. If you have permission to write in a directory you can always "edit" a file by erasing it and recreating a new copy of it. This does not require permission to modify the file since if there was a hard-link to it in another directory it would still be there, unchanged.

Comment: Hmm. Even when taking the editor out of the picture, Vim still says it's editing a read-only file, but yet it actually lets you save?

Comment: Yes. I just tried it. Vim did require using the exclamation mark as in "w!" to force the write. If you do that then vim will use any trick it has in order to write the file.

Comment: I think if you force a save in Vim, it changes the permissions (if it can), saves the file, and then changes them back. It certainly _looks like_ it's saved over a read-only file. I guess the moral is that you can't rely on Vim to tell you what the file permissions are.

Answer (score 1):

There is code inside vim that does a pretty good job of deciding when a file has been opened by someone else with another editor for writing, and it stops you from a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) for file write.

Vim is telling you to wait very patiently for the other person to be done writing that file.

Learn more with `:help W10`

**Reproduce this bug in vim 9.0:**

1. Make a `/tmp/file.txt` owned by youruser with `rw-r--r--`
2. Open two unique terminals to /tmp/
3. Open file.txt for writing in one using vim.
4. Vim will mark the file as read only awaiting write, since someone else has it open for writing.
5. Open file.txt for writing in one using vim in the other terminal.

**You get:**

> "-- INSERT -- W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file"

**Solutions:**

Find the other instance of vim that has locked your file for writing and close that instance of vim.  Done

Or if you don't have access to the other terminal, or the instance of the other editor died without releasing its read only lock, or if it's from another person who's opened the file for writing on a session from a different computer, then the only thing I know that can clear all of those conditions is rebooting the computer.

If you want more control over this, you'll have to uncover how vim is deciding when a file is readonly for writing and find out where this information is being stored and clear it manually.

Comment: When we open the file in first terminal a .swp file is created and vi gives a warning if you attempt to open the file in the second terminal. That prevents from unintended changes and unexpected outputs. Even though we can override the warning, make changes and force write to seemingly readonly file by :rw!